# how do I programmatically create an ImageButton with an image?

Tags: android, button, imagebutton, glsurfaceview

I'm trying to add an ImageButton over a GLSurfaceView. Adding regular buttons with text is already done and appears on my tablet. Creating an ImageButton works only halfway though. When I created my ImageButton programmatically, it only shows the box for the button, but will not load the basic android icon. Here is my code:

```
LinearLayout btnLO = new LinearLayout(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLO = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
// button margins
paramsLO.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
// button height/width *pixels*
paramsLO.height = 75;
paramsLO.width = 75;

btnLO.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
btnLO.setBackgroundColor(5); // not working correctly

//buttons
Button b1 = new Button(this);
Button b2 = new Button(this);
Button b3 = new Button(this);

int i1Btn = 0;
ImageButton i1 = new ImageButton(this);
i1Btn = R.drawable.icon;
i1.setImageResource(i1Btn);

//text for buttons
b1.setText("Arrow");
b2.setText("Move");
b3.setText("Scale");


//displays buttons with parameters (if any)
btnLO.addView(b1, paramsLO);
btnLO.addView(b2, paramsLO);
btnLO.addView(b3, paramsLO);
btnLO.addView(i1, paramsLO);

btnLO.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

this.addContentView(btnLO, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Again, b1-b3 are regular buttons with text on them. They work perfectly. But the "il" ImageButton only shows the button portion without the icon. Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Comment: Try cleaning your project and build again.

Comment: Wow... It was just that simple yet I've been on this for 3 hours splitting brain cells... lol Thx!